# how to get svg content from VaadinIcon

Tags: vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I am using com.vaadin.flow.component.icon.VaadinIcon ,

how can I get svg content/tag from VaadinIcon.java ?

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: i have to export pdf  report with vaadinIcon which is used on the UI.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to get the SVG from the component. But you could use the SVG from the Github Repo: https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-icons/tree/master/assets/svg

Comment: Continuing from what Simon wrote, the situation is such that the SVG content is only included in the client-side bundle that gets loaded in the browser, but it isn't defined in a location that is easily accessible from Java.

Comment: thanks @SimonMartinelli .

I found alternate solution  like  you mentioned that get icon from assets.
VaadinIcon 14  internally referring  to webjars :
 vaadin-icons-4.3.2.jar\META-INF\resources\webjars\vaadin-icons\assets\svg\   which is under my  web application context , so I was able to read  and attach with my pdf report.

Comment: Great! Can you please add this to the answer because other developers might be interested in your solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

the vaadin icon assets present under
webcontext/webjars/vaadin-icons/assets/svg/icon-name.svg  , you can get the svg content by reading the file.

using spring applicationContext

Resource resource = applicationContext.getResource("/webjars/vaadin-icons/assets/svg/icon-name.svg);

icon-name ->  is whatever the name of icon.